# How can i embbed two different galleries in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, gallery

I have a created a custom post type 'services'.I want to upload and embed two different galleries.
I researched and got various codes to create meta boxes from where one can upload the image.

But the problem is that i am only able to upload only one image in one meta box and not the whole gallery.

Please help me out how can i do this or suggest me some another alternative

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Services
Plugin URI: 
Description: post types
Author: Amritanshu Kalia
Author URI: 
License: GPLv2 or later
*/
define( 'ROOT', plugins_url( '', __FILE__ ) );
define( 'STYLES', ROOT . '/css/' );
define( 'SCRIPTS', ROOT . '/js/' );
// Registers the new post type and taxonomy

function wpt_services_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'services',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Services' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'services' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New services' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New services' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit service' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'Add New service' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View service' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search service' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'No services found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No services found in trash' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title','thumbnail', 'comments','page-attributes' ),
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'rewrite' => array("slug" => "services"), // Permalinks format
            'menu_position' => 6,             
            'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_services_metaboxes',
            'show_ui'=>true,
            'query_var'=>true
            )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpt_services_posttype' );     


/*Now we add the meta boxes to the services*/
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_services_metaboxes');
function add_services_metaboxes() {     
    add_meta_box( 'services' . '_details' , 'Media Library', 'my_meta_box_details', 'services', 'normal', 'high' );
}    

function my_meta_box_details () {
    global $post;
    $post_ID = $post->ID; // global used by get_upload_iframe_src
    printf( "<iframe frameborder='0' src=' %s ' style='width: 100%%; height: 400px;'> </iframe>", get_upload_iframe_src('media') );
  }
?>
```

Comment: Which code have you tried?

Comment: @cybmeta i have inserted the code above

Comment: Although your code may not be the best solution from my point of view, I don't understand why you say that you can upload only one image when actually you can upload an **unlimited number of images**.

Comment: @cybmeta i think you are right .. i am able to create the gallery but how do i display the gallery on the front end

Comment: Your code is storing the images as attached files of current post; [this can help you](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61393/get-images-attached-to-post). And please, [edit the question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/173904/edit) to describe better your actual problem.

Comment: @cybmeta I am able to get all the images but the problem is it fetches all the images from the 2 different galleries together

Comment: Or you have any other suggestion or code

Comment: I was doing it all wronng . i didn't know that i can embed more than one gallery.                                            Problem solved ,, anyways thanks @cybmeta for taking your time out and helping me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedded two galleries in the order according to my need. Then used the `get_post_galleries`
to get the galleries in an array.